# Spring Boot 2 can't read property as String

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

While migrating a Spring Boot application from Spring Boot 1.4.0 to Spring Boot 2, I started getting errors on trying to read a property from my .properties file.

In the properties file, the property is defined as:

`environment=dev`

And in one of my classes, I am importing the property through the `@Value` annotation, like this:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class CustomUserFilter extends SwitchUserFilter {
    ...
    @Value("${environment}")
    private String environment;
    ...
```

The class above overrides `org.springframework.security.web.authentication.switchuser.SwitchUserFilter`, to enable users to switch roles.

Until Spring Boot 1.4.0, I was able to import this property in my class as a String. However, ever since migrating to Spring Boot 2, I get the following compile-time error:

> Error:(43, 20) java: getEnvironment() in demo.config.CustomUserFilter
>   cannot implement getEnvironment() in
>   org.springframework.core.env.EnvironmentCapable   return type
>   java.lang.String is not compatible with
>   org.springframework.core.env.Environment

I'm not sure why this is happening. I also tried changing the type of this variable to `Environment (org.springframework.core.env.Environment)` (as shown below):

```
...
@Value("${environment}")
private Environment environment;
...
```

, but then I started getting the following error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'switchUserFilter': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'environment'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'org.springframework.core.env.Environment'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'org.springframework.core.env.Environment': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:584)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:370)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:572)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:204)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:226)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAsRegistrationBean(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:182)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAsRegistrationBean(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:177)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAdaptableBeans(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:159)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.<init>(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:81)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.getServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:261)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.selfInitialize(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:234)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:185)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:154)
    ... 52 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'org.springframework.core.env.Environment'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'org.springframework.core.env.Environment': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterSupport.doConvert(TypeConverterSupport.java:77)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterSupport.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterSupport.java:60)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1089)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1062)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:581)
    ... 70 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'org.springframework.core.env.Environment': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:117)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterSupport.doConvert(TypeConverterSupport.java:70)
    ... 74 more
```

Any clues as to what could be wrong? I am using **Spring Boot 2.0**, **Spring 5**, **Java 11**, and **Tomcat 8.5.35**. Thanks!

Comment: Add `@Configuration` above class declaration and check if it works

Comment: `Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'org.springframework.core.env.Environment'` seemly you missing few important lines of code in the question.

Comment: MaruthiAdithya I already have a separate @Configuration class defined, which is where I try to initialize a bean of the class above. But I tried adding it in this class as well, didn't work.

Comment: @DoNhuVy All I did to get that error was change from `private String environment;` to `private Environment environment;`

Comment: This link may be helpful for you https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config . I mean the problem may be not stand at your posted code, it happens at another position.

Comment: What happens if you change the name of the property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was unrelated to Spring Boot. My class above extends `org.springframework.security.web.authentication.switchuser.SwitchUserFilter`, which further extends `org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean`. This `GenericFilterBean` class also has an attribute `private Environment environment;`. Further, this class was modified in Spring 5 release to include a getter method on this attribute. Spring 5 introduced a `getEnvironment()` with return type `Environment` in class `GenericFilterBean`, which was conflicting with my `getEnvironment()` with return type `String`.

To avoid this conflict, I simply changed the name of my attribute from `environment` to `env` and things worked after that.

Comment: Cool - thank you for posting the solution.  Q: Which version of Spring was your Spring Boot 1.4.0 running under.  Please "accept" your answer.

Comment: @paulsm4 StackOverflow won't let me accept before the next two days, apparently. I  was running Spring 4.3.2 with Spring Boot 1.4. Upgraded to Spring 5.0.11 with Spring Boot 2.0.

Comment: Got it.  I thought there might have been a name collision between your variable and the new "Environment" abstraction, introduced in Spring 3.1.

Comment: @paulsm4 Yeah, it was actually not the `environment` attribute itself, but the getter on it. Spring 5 introduced a `getEnvironment()` with return type `Environment`, which was conflicting with my `getEnvironment()` with return type `String`.

Answer (score 0):

Add @Component to your class and try that